# Detect phone with a Custom ROM in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Can I do something to run applications from Eclipse directly on the phone while I have Custom ROM on it? Or I have to go back to stock Android ROM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run apps from Eclipse, Xamarin or other IDE if you have ADB enabled on the phone and ADB drivers installed on your computer.

To check if you have ADB Drivers installed, open CMD/Terminal, navigate to "SDK_Location/platform-tools" and then run: "adb devices", you should have a response with something like this:

[image]

Those numbers are my android adb id, may change for your device, if you have not drivers installed, will not get any number.